# Proving that $a_i,b_i \to 0$ where $a_{i+1} := |b_i - a_i|$ and $b_{i+1} := |a_i - a_{i+1}|$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, integer-lattices

Let $a_0 := 1$ and $b_0 := \sqrt{2}$, and define
\begin{align*}
a_{i+1} &:= |b_i - a_i| \\
b_{i+1} &:= |a_i - a_{i+1}|
\end{align*}
Prove that $\lim_{i \to \infty}{a_i} = 0$ and $\lim_{i \to \infty}{b_i} = 0$.

Context: I am given the set $L := \{a+b\sqrt{2} : a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, and I want to prove it is NOT a lattice over $\mathbb{R}$, since it is not discrete.
My idea to solve it was to build a sequence converging to $0$ and I came up with this sequence.
Intuitively/empirically seems to be converging to $0$, but I am having trouble proving it formally. Does anyone have any idea or hint?

Comment: You probably don't need to solve this problem about sequences. The statement that you are trying to prove in the first place ($L$ not discrete) is the consequence of [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem).

Comment: @StinkingBishop Uh, indeed, thanks! But honestly now I am still curious to see how to prove the convergence of this sequence.

Comment: @StinkingBishop By the way, the application of the Dirichlet's approximation would still not be so straightforward, because I cannot build rational numbers in the lattice (as additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Well, take $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ (the symbols from Wikipedia) and for every $N$ you can find $p,q$ such. that $|q\sqrt{2}-p|<\frac{1}{N}$. Thus, you can find numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ arbitrarily close to zero. (Take $a=-p, b=q$.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Uh, I was focusing too much on the "any real number has a sequence of good rational approximations" part. Thanks for the explicit answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove, by induction that

$$a_n = \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)^n, ~~b_n = \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)^{n-1} - \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)^n. \tag1 $$

---

Empirically true for $n=1$.

$$a_{n+1} = |b_n - a_n| = |\left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)^{n-1} \times [ 1 - 2(\sqrt{2} - 1) ]|$$

$$ = |\left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)^{n-1}  \times (3 - 2\sqrt{2})|$$

$$ = |\left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)^{n-1} \times \left(\sqrt{2} 
- 1\right)^2| = \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)^{n+1}.$$

Therefore,

$$b_{n+1} = |a_{n+1} - a_{n}| = \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)^n - \left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)^{n+1}.$$

So, (1) above is proven.

Further, it is immediate from (1) above that as $n \to \infty, a_n \to 0.$

Finally, $b_n$ may be re-written

$$\left(\sqrt{2 - 1}\right)^{n-1} [1 - (\sqrt{2} - 1)] = 
(2-\sqrt{2})a_{n-1}.$$

So, as $n \to \infty, b_n \to 0.$

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Can I ask you how did you come up with the induction thesis in the first place? Just by intuition?

Comment: @Ronteg No, by elbow grease.  I manually charted $a_n,b_n$ for $n \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$, and noticed how, for $a_n$, the expressions changed from $R - S\sqrt{2}$ to $T\sqrt{2} - U$ to $V - W\sqrt{2}$.  Then, I just sat and meditated.

Comment: Back to the motivation, you only need $(\sqrt{2}-1)^n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Justauser My intuition isn't that strong, and my knowledge of Real Analysis is *shallow*.  For example, I have never heard of Dirichlet.  So, I needed to **see** the values, and think about them.  Hence, the elbow grease.

Comment: @user2661923 what you did is amazing, as people often say mathematics might very well be an experimental subject in practice. I just want to say to Ronteg that we don't really need $b_n$ once this clears.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to show $L$ is discrete, it's much simpler than Dirichlet's theorem: the sequence $\{x_n=a_n+b_n\sqrt{2}| b_n = n, a=-\lfloor b\sqrt 2\rfloor\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is an infinite bounded subset of $[0, 1)$. So $L$ cannot be discrete. To be more precise, it contains a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_i}\}$, then $|x_{n_i}-x_{n_j}|>0$ can be arbitrarily small for suitable $i,j$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is quite straightforward indeed.
But I still hope someone can help me out with that sequence, otherwise I will keep thinking about it for weeks.